# get nlargest values from multi index data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a data frame that looks like following image:
[image]

Here uid and id are indexes. This data frame was converted from a single index dataframe, so there are duplicate values for some columns. For each *uid*, all values for *avg_diff* are same, but different uid will have different values for this field. I want to get the largest 10 *avg_diff* values, with different uids.

**Note**: This is a huge data frame, so I am looking for the most optimized way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can first remove duplicates by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `~` is for invert boolean mask.

Then use [`DataFrame.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) or [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'uid':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3], 'id':[2,3,4,5,6,1,3], 
                   'avg_diff':[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3]})
df = df.set_index('uid').set_index('id', drop=False, append=True)
print (df)
        avg_diff  id
uid id              
1   2        0.1   2
    3        0.1   3
    4        0.1   4
2   5        0.2   5
    6        0.2   6
3   1        0.3   1
    3        0.3   3
```

---

```
mask = df.index.get_level_values('uid').duplicated() 
print (~mask)
[ True False False  True False  True False]

df = df[~mask].nlargest(2, 'avg_diff')
print (df)
        avg_diff  id
uid id              
3   1        0.3   1
2   5        0.2   5
```

Another solution:

```
mask = df.index.get_level_values('uid').duplicated() 
print (~mask)
[ True False False  True False  True False]

df = df[~mask].sort_values('avg_diff', ascending=False).head(2)
print (df)

        avg_diff  id
uid id              
3   1        0.3   1
2   5        0.2   5
```

Comment: Use `print (df[~mask].nsmallest(2, 'avg_diff'))`

Comment: Or `df[~mask].sort_values('avg_diff').head(2)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you just need to drop duplicates of "uid" and then sort by avr_diff

```
unique_uid = data.reset_index().drop_duplicates("uid").set_index("uid")
print(unique_uid["avr_diff"].sort_values(ascending=False)[:10])
```